Add event listener to routes childs
In React I want to add an event handler to the parent of route childs off the routes collection. I have tried already a lot but I don't get it working.
function App() {
return (
    <WebsiteLayout>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/">
                <Route index element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
                <Route path="/rubrieken" element={<Rubrieken />} />
                <Route path="/producten" element={<Producten />}/>
                <Route path="/product" element={<Product />} />
                <Route path="/bestellen" element={<Bestellen /> } />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    </WebsiteLayout>
);}


function RemapChildren() {
    try {
        return (
            React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
                React.Children.map(child.props.children, (subchild) => {
                    React.Children.map(subchild.props.children, (routechild) => {
                        return (React.cloneElement(routechild, { setShoppingCartItems: { updateShoppingCartItems } }))
                    });
                    return (React.cloneElement(subchild));
                });
                return (React.cloneElement(child));
            }));
    }
    catch (err) {
        var test = err;
    }
}

function renderPage() {
    return (
       <RemapChildren />
    );
}

As you can see I tried to Remap the children and a an eventhandler to it using React.cloneElement. However the props in my routed components are empty.

Just to be clear, do you want to add event handlers to the components wrapped by the Routes?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, I want to add the function updateShoppingcartItems as an event handler to the components wrapped by the Routes. So that the Child components can make a call to this function.
